# sort values where their corresponding integers are same

Tags: java, sorting, object

I have an input with attributes string and number
I have to sort the strings corresponding to the numbers and if two strings have the same corresponding numbers then the strings should be sorted lexicographically.

e.g input

abc 2
hi 3
bye 3

output

bye 3
hi 3
abc 2

How to implement this in java .What data structure should i choose to solve this problem?

Comment: Is the input just a string?

Comment: @ManishGiri yes

Comment: @ManishGiri abc has value 2, hi has a value of 3 and bye has a value of 3

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

// required data structure
class A
{
String s;
int num;
}

class B
{
public static void main(String arg[])
{
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
String input=sc.nextLine();     //reading input

StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(input);

Vector<A> v=new Vector<A>();        //for storing objects of class A

while(st.hasMoreTokens())       
{
A a=new A();        //creating objects
a.s=st.nextToken();
a.num=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
v.add(a);
}

//sort

for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<v.size()-1;j++)
    {
        if(v.get(j).num<v.get(j+1).num)
        {
        A temp=v.get(j);
        v.set(j,v.get(j+1));
        v.set(j+1,temp);
        }
        else
        if(v.get(j).num==v.get(j+1).num)
        {
            if(v.get(j).s.compareTo(v.get(j+1).s)>0)
            {
            A temp=v.get(j);
            v.set(j,v.get(j+1));
            v.set(j+1,temp);
            }
        }
    }
}       //sort end

for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++)
System.out.print(v.get(i).s+" "+v.get(i).num+" ");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use a priority queue and have a storer class that 
overrides CompareTo. Like so:

```
/**
 * A container for data tuples, eg in "abc 2 hi 3 bye 3 q 2 a 1"
 * (abc 2) would be one DataValue Object
 * 
 * make it implement comparable and override compare to so that the objects with higher num 
 * values are considered a "higher priority"
 * @author Dragos
 *
 */
public class DataValue implements Comparable<DataValue> {

    private String str;
    private Integer num;

    public DataValue(String str, Integer num) {
        this.str = str;
        this.num = num;
    }


    @Override
    public int compareTo(DataValue o) {
        if (o.num > this.num)
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return str + " " + num;
    }

    // GETTERS:

    public String getStr() {
        return str;
    }

    public Integer getNum() {
        return num;
    }

}
```

and then the main class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class SortingStrings {

    private static PriorityQueue <DataValue> pq = new PriorityQueue<DataValue>();

    public static void main (String [] args) {

        String inputString = "abc 2 hi 3 bye 3 q 2 a 1";
        // split the input into an array:
        String [] asArray = inputString.split(" ");

        // now load all the string and integer values into their own array lists:
        List<String> allSubStrings = new ArrayList<String> ();
        List<Integer> allSubNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer> ();


        for (int i = 0; i< asArray.length; i++) {

            // for even positions:
            if (i%2 == 0) 
                // we parse a string
                allSubStrings.add(asArray[i]);

            // for odd positions
            else 
                // we parse a number, and are ready to create a DataValue Object:
                allSubNumbers.add(Integer.parseInt(asArray[i]));

        }

        // now go through both array lists creating DataValue objects and adding them to the PriorityQueue:
        for (int i = 0; i < allSubStrings.size(); i++) {
            pq.add(new DataValue(allSubStrings.get(i),allSubNumbers.get(i)));
        }

        // now pop from the priority queue to get the resulting string:
        for (int i = 0; i < allSubNumbers.size(); i ++) {
            System.out.print(pq.remove() + " ");
        }


    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.Console;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class s1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String ss=sc.nextLine();
        String[] a;
        String temp;
        a = ss.split(" ");

        //sort 
        for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i += 2) {
            for (int j = i + 2; j < a.length; j += 2) {
                if (Integer.parseInt(a[i]) < Integer.parseInt(a[j])) {
                    //swapping if numbers were different
                    temp = a[i];
                    a[i] = a[j];
                    a[j] = temp;
                    temp = a[i - 1];
                    a[i - 1] = a[j - 1];
                    a[j - 1] = temp;

                } else if (Integer.parseInt(a[i]) == Integer.parseInt(a[j])) {
                    if (a[i - 1].compareTo(a[j - 1]) > 0) {
                        //swapping if numbers were same, then checking alphabets
                        temp = a[i];
                        a[i] = a[j];
                        a[j] = temp;
                        temp = a[i - 1];
                        a[i - 1] = a[j - 1];
                        a[j - 1] = temp;
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            System.out.print(a[i]+" ");

    }

}
```